# Initializing a boolean array to false

Tags: java, arrays

I have this piece of code below. How do I initialize each element = false?

```
boolean[] seats = new boolean[10]
```

I saw a similar question. But, the second line didnt make sense to me (Can you explain the 2nd line?).

```
 Boolean[] array = new Boolean[size];
 Arrays.fill(array, Boolean.FALSE);
```

Comment: "Next Question" No. Don't change the question. [Ask a new one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Changing the question invalidates all the existing answers.

Comment: You mean start a new thread outside of this one?

Comment: Yes, he wants you to ask a new question (i.e. a whole new thread)

Answer (score 62, accepted):

The default value for the elements in a `boolean[]` is false. You don't need to do anything.

The reason it's necessary for `Boolean[]` is because the default value is `null`.

---

To initialize to true, use the [overload](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#fill%28boolean%5b%5d,%20boolean%29) of `Arrays.fill` that accepts a `boolean[]`.

```
boolean[] seats = new boolean[10];
Arrays.fill(seats, true);
```

See it working online: [ideone](http://ideone.com/pvoFP)

Comment: That's what I thought. Thanks

Comment: Ok, how do I initialize it to True then?

Comment: Simple `Arrays.fill(array, Boolean.TRUE);`

Comment: Ok, my goal is to read an input from the user. If the user enters '1' initialize an elements 1-5 to be true. if '2' is entered initialize element from 5-10 to be true.

Comment: Sure, sorry about the confusion. I have posted it above.

Answer (score 4):

A `boolean` is initialized to `false` by default. So you need not to do anything specific here. When you create an array of booleans and don't initialize it all the elements will be be `false`.

> how do I initialize it to True then?

Simple `Arrays.fill(array, Boolean.TRUE);`